# How to get first part of a URL

Tags: php, regex, url

can anyone help me to piece together the puzzled I'm facing. Lets say I have url's

```
/some-work/

/store/bread/alloy/
```

and in both of these cases I wanna fetch the first part from it. i.e. `some-work`, `store`.

Now I've used `parse_url(get_permalink())` to get the array of the url and then fetch the `path` index of the array to fetch the above string. Now I have also checked `strstr` PHP function, but I am unable to make it work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function like as

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/some-work/";
$extracted = array_filter(explode("/",parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH)));
echo current($extracted);//some-work
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/447659)

Comment: So I guess I'm feting the url using the procedure that I stated above i.e. `parse_url(get_permalink())` right? Thanks for the fast answer. Quick question why we cant use `strstr` here?

Comment: Cause `strstr` is used for finding the first occurrence of a string which won't work over here

Comment: [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first occurrence of needle **to the end of haystack**.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer and explanation :)